# Options for replacing mortise lock with keyless lock

Tags: doors, lock

The main door to my apartment has a Baldwin interlocked mortise deadbolt/lockset combination... basically one of these:

[image]

I would like to replace this with some kind of electronic, keyless system, but all the ones that look any good are designed for cylindrical-drilled deadbolts.

Any suggestions?

(I am aware that one option would be [filling in the mortise cavity and starting from scratch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/how-do-i-replace-mortise-locks-with-bored-cylindrical-locks), but that's rather a bigger project than I had been hoping for)

Comment: This could be an expensive endeavor. Replacing some doors may even be cheaper.  BTW  Never heard how your liquor cabinet disaster worked out from last December.

Comment: oh yeah :) I accepted [your answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/80644/156) over on that question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly mortise-form-factor smart locks; I installed one of them last year. They tend to be commercial-grade rather than home-grade; more durable and able to handle more complex programming but also more expensive.

At one point several manufacturers were offering smart mortise cylinders, which did a digital handshake with a powered key to make the key extremely difficult to duplicate. Thay would install into your current latch mechanism. But I presume that isn't what you:re looking for.

If you were a paying customer I'd ask you to be more specific about what you need and then do a search thru the manufacturers. A full-time locksmith would be more aware if current product lines and would find the answer faster.